# Analog switch unpowered state

Tags: power, mosfet, analog, switches, leakage-current

The board I am designing is a test board for another battery powered PCBA. I am using a [MAX4737EUD+](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX4737-MAX4739.pdf) and a [TMUX1101DBVR](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tmux1101) in my project to switch signals and power to the PCBA under test. They are also used to drain power in order to reset the PCBA under test:

[image]

My issue is that when no power is being supplied to the test board, source and drain on the chip seem to be shorted as well as VDD_STS to 5 V. This is causing weird things to happen when the test board is powered off, and draining of the battery on the test PCBA.

Does anyone know more about analog switches in their unpowered state?

Comment: an analog switch IC is not a real switch. It's a transistor circuit that simulates a switch for some purposes.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds normal for any chip, not just analog mux. No signal voltage can exceed the supply voltage, and if there is no supply voltage, there can be no signal voltages either. There is nothing special about that.